# How to use Equal in models passed to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am having to use if/else statements to output a currency value tied to a selection the user makes. Something like:

```
@if (Model.ProcessingRadioButtons.Equals("Standard"))
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.priceProcessingStandard)
}
else if (Model.ProcessingRadioButtons.Equals("Expedited"))
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.priceProcessingExpedited)
}
else if (Model.ProcessingRadioButtons.Equals("Urgent"))
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.priceProcessingUrgent)
}
```

But it is not displaying anything based on the radio button I select, so I know that the `if`/`else if` statements are wrong. I turned the last `else if` into an `else` and took out the `(Model.ProcessingRadioButtons.Equal("Urgent"))` and it displays 500 (see below for price entities).

This is the enum for the radiobutton:

```
public enum Processing
{
    Standard,
    Expedited,
    Urgent
}
```

And the radio button entity (using helpers to accomplish the radio button):

```
public Processing? ProcessingRadioButtons { get; set; }
```

These are the entities for price:

```
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
public decimal priceProcessingStandard = 0;

[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
public decimal priceProcessingExpedited = 250;

[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
public decimal priceProcessingUrgent= 500;
```

Any guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sending a model with the ProcessingRadioButtons property set?

Aside that, why not using:

```
@if (Model.ProcessingRadioButtons == Processing.Standard)
```

it is simpler and don't relies on magic strings.

Comment: Thanks. Your solution allows the currency sign `$` to display. Not sure why, otherwise both answers are correct but yours is more succinct.

Comment: Any thoughts as to why I have to "Resolve" `Processing` to be `Namespace.ViewModels.MyData.Processing`? I have the `@using` statement obviously.

Comment: instead of placing the "@using" statement, you can simple use the full qualified name... in your case "Namespace.ViewModels.MyData.Processing"... and si if that is the correct one, and the move it to the @using.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797715/how-can-i-sum-two-different-selections-passed-to-model. Having started the question then getting caught up at work I forgot to ask the second part of my question (note that I changed the title here)

Answer (score 1):

If ProcessingRadioButtons is an enum you need to compare to that - not to a string. Try ...   .Equals(Processing.Standard) instead.

Comment: Although your answer is correct and you answered first, gave credit to Romias. In both instances I had to "Resolve" the namespace issue with using `Processing`, in which case its `Namespace.ViewModels.MyData.Processing`. But your solution would not display the currency sign `$` in the view and I am not sure why.

Comment: Doesnt matter to me. As far as I can see we both suggested the same thing, with different flavors of equality comparisons only. The display of the currency symbol doesn't have to do with the if-statement, but with how the DisplayFor-function is used. Glad it worked out for you though!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797715/how-can-i-sum-two-different-selections-passed-to-model. Having started the question then getting caught up at work I forgot to ask the second part of my question (note that I changed the title here)