# How can I SUM two different selections passed to model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, sum

I am taking a prior question one step further (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793848/how-to-use-equal-in-models-passed-to-view)), I am trying to figure out how to `sum` two (or more) selections the user makes with, for example, a radio button list. The selection the user makes is tied to an entity that contains a static currency value using `if/else if` statements.

These are the entities for price:

```
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
public decimal priceProcessingStandard = 0;

[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
public decimal priceProcessingExpedited = 250;

[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
public decimal priceSubmissionOnline = 0;

[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
public decimal priceSubmissionManual = 200;
```

So, if I have two sets of `if/else if` statements such as:

```
@if (Model.ProcessingRadioButtons == Processing.Standard)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.priceProcessingStandard)
}
else if (Model.ProcessingRadioButtons == Processing.Expedited)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.priceProcessingExpedited)
}
...
@if (Model.SubmissionRadioButtons == Submission.Online)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.priceSubmissionOnline)
}
else if (Model.SubmissionRadioButtons == Submission.Manual)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.priceSubmissionManual)
}
```

and the user makes selections in the two separate radio button lists corresponding to `Processing.Expedited` and `Submission.Manual`, the code will respectively display `$250.00` and `$200.00`.

I cannot, however, figure out how to `sum` those two to display `$450.00`.  Bear in mind, I do not know the selections before hand, so doing `priceProcessingExpedited + priceSubmissionManual` in a function and then calling it will obviously not work. Also, I am doing about 10-15 of these but I only used two simple ones as an example of what I am trying to accomplish (so the fact that the other two choices are `$0.00` doesn't mean anything because there are varying prices for other choices that I left out).

Any guidance?

**UPDATE:**
Based on suggestion in answer, I am doing this:

```
Model.calculated =
    Model.priceSolution +
    ((Model.ProcessingRadioButtons == Processing.Standard) ?
    Model.priceProcessingStandard :
    (Model.ProcessingRadioButtons == Processing.Expedited) ?
    Model.priceProcessingExpedited :
    Model.priceProcessingUrgent);
```

Some notes:

1. `priceSolution` is a static value that I use as a base (it's the base value plus the user selections).
2. I am using `calculated` in the ViewModel and `get; set;`'ing it.
3. I left out the `Namespace.ViewModels.MyData` before `Processing.` for brevity.
4. I left out `Submission` for brevity as it's just a `+` then the same logic as in `Processing`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do know the selections before hand considering your `@if (Model.SubmissionRadioButtions == Submission.Online)` is a test against values currently held by the model - even if this is only after a POST.

As such, you should create a property in your view model that also performs these tests and sums the appropriate fields.

If you don't want this property displayed *before* the POST, make the property return a nullable type and wrap the view with `@if(MySum.HasValue) { @Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.MySum) }`

Comment: I made a semantic error in explaining myself. I know the choices, yes, I do not know before hand what a particular user will select is what I meant to say. I previously tried to create a property in the view model, but I mucked it up with all the different choices. I was just hoping there was a cleaner way to `sum` what is ultimately displayed.

Comment: After some research your advice led me to the correct answer. Thanks. See update in question.